# How to launch game with urls with python?

Tags: python, url

Using and opening Epic Games Launcher games, I have noticed that they run by using a strange url from the desktop icon. I was wondering, how can I get python to get this to launch the game? (I have already tried running the game's exe in its respective file location, but that does nothing)

Example url, with the desktop icon being a .url file extension

```
com.epicgames.launcher://apps/9773aa1aa54f4f7b80e44bef04986cea%3A530145df28a24424923f5828cc9031a1%3ASugar?action=launch&silent=true
```

I have tried running the exe file, but I can't figure out how to run that specific url, maybe I could pass it as a command line argument into the exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only Windows uses `.url` extensions for shortcuts. You could try using `subprocess` module

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

game = "com.epicgames.launcher://apps/9773aa1aa54f4f7b80e44bef04986cea%3A530145df28a24424923f5828cc9031a1%3ASugar?action=launch&silent=true"
Popen(["explorer", game], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
```

Otherwise, you can also call the `exe` from there, too.

Comment: That was odd, it just opened the documents folder...

Comment: That's what `explorer.exe` does, yes... I haven't tried since I don't use Windows, but this is almost what a `.url` file already does.

Comment: Ah I see, I'm sorry, it didn't do anything else, what was supposed to happen?

Comment: I guess you could try setting `game` to `r'C:\Users\name\Desktop\file.url'` and see what that does

Comment: It's "supposed" to open the Epic Game launcher. Alternatively, just go find the game exe file itself.

Comment: Nope. I'm sorry no workie

Comment: Wait it works using it as a raw string with backslashes, thank you so much!